# Swift: How do I use the KeyboardShortcuts package in a CLI app?

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to the Swift language. I'm trying to use the [KeyboardShortcuts](https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts) package in my CLI application, but it doesn't work. See an example:

```swift
import KeyboardShortcuts

extension KeyboardShortcuts.Name {
    static let foobar = Self("foobar", default: .init(.k, modifiers: [.command, .option, .control]))
}

KeyboardShortcuts.onKeyUp(for: .foobar) {
    print("foobar")
}
```

If you compile and run the code above it will ***not*** hang and listen for your keyboard input, it will finish the execution almost immediately. So what am I doing wrong? How do I make it listen to my keyboard input and not finish the execution?

Comment: Not a full answer, but: right now, there's nothing in your code that would keep your CLI alive and running past the end of the last line of code. In order to do that, you need to use a [RunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop) to run indefinitely and receive UI and other events. Adding `RunLoop.main.run()` as the last line in your file should keep the CLI alive. If you try that out, do you get key events as expected?

Comment: @ItaiFerber thank you for your advise, if I add `RunLoop.main.run()`, the app seems to be running indefinitely but the keyboard shortcut is not working anyway

Comment: I don't know how `KeyboardShortcuts` works, but it appears that you might need to create an actual `Recorder` for registering for the shortcut? Otherwise I don't think the `onKeyUp` will do anything.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I guess you could be right, but I've provided a default hotkey, so I was thinking it should work without a `Recorder`. Anyway, will try to use a `Recorder` tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: How are keyboard shortcuts supposed to work with a common line tool?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't see a reason why it should not work. Maybe I was wrong calling it a CLI app. Let's say I want an app without a graphical interface which works in the background and makes some actions (launches Google Chrome, for example) when a keyboard shortcut is pressed